# javascript array push value of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference

I am trying to create an array of objects, however when I am pushing onto my array it is adding a reference to the object rather than copying the values.

```
var nestedOrgList = [];
var tempTopOrg = {};

var i = 0;
while (typeof divList[i] !== 'undefined') {
    tempTopOrg.org = divList[i++]; // increment i after we assign this
    tempTopOrg.suborgs = [];

    while ($(divList[i]).has('.expand').length < 1 && i < divList.length) {
        tempTopOrg.suborgs.push(divList[i++]);
    }

    nestedOrgList.push(tempTopOrg);
};
```

Is there a better way to do this? Or do I need to do a manual copy?

```
nestedOrgList[insertIndex].org = tempTopOrg.org;
// etc..
insertIndex++;
```

Comment: @NuclearGhost JavaScript passes *values* (hint: objects *are* values) and, just like during an assignment, those *values* are *not* copied/cloned/duplicated in the process. There is *no* use of "reference" describing this behavior in the ECMAScript specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the following answer

[How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)

The JSperf

http://jsperf.com/cloning-an-object/82

definitely JavaScript should have a way natively to copy references.

Comment: Thank you for the reference to that answer

Answer (score 0):

A common method if speed is not a critical goal is to encode/decode the object using JSON:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(tempTopOrg);
nestedOrgList.push( JSON.parse(json) );
```

Answer (score 0):

javascript passes objects and arrays by reference, so you will have to make a copy before pushing,

```
myarray.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)));
```

is quick and dirty and probably has performance issues,

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object/122704#122704) tries to tackle cloning of objects.

Answer (score 0):

to make a deep copy use

```
var newcopy = temp.slice(0);
```

and to filter undefined and null values use

```
newcopy  = newcopy.filter(function(e){ return e });
```